# Armazenar valor de um atributo em uma variável em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho esse seguinte *menu*:

```
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="a glyphicon glyphicon-home">
    </i><span>Inicial</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="b glyphicon glyphicon-user">
</i>
    <span>Perfil</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="c glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
</i>
    <span>Calendário</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="d glyphicon glyphicon-file">
</i>
    <span>Material Didático</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="e glyphicon glyphicon-stats">
</i>
    <span>Frequencias</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="f glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt">
</i>
    <span>Notas</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="g glyphicon glyphicon-usd">
</i>
    <span>Financeiro</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="h glyphicon glyphicon-book">
    </i><span>Biblioteca</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="j glyphicon glyphicon-cog">
</i>
    <span>Configurações</span></a>
</li>
```

e tenho esse código jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("a#nav").click(function(){

     });
});
```

o que eu preciso é quando eu clicar por exemplo no menu eu pegar o valor do `class` e colocar em uma variável, por exemplo se eu ***clicasse*** no primeiro "Inicial" eu pegasse o valor da `class`, que no caso seria o **a**.

Comment: Não é bom ter vários `a` com o mesmo id. Passe esse nav para uma classe, e busque com $('a.nav').click

Comment: Concordo com @DavidAlves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.nav').click(function(){
        var classes = $(this).find('i').attr('class');
        var classe = classes.charAt(0);
    });
});
```

Contudo, isso não resolve se o nome da classe que quer pegar tenha mais do que um caractere e se ela não estiver no começo da declaração.

E de acordo com comentário de @DanielAlves na pergunta não duplique um `id` utilize classes para identificar seus links e é interessante o `href` ter um #! porque assim a página não dá "scroll":

```
<li><a class="nav" href="#!"><i class="a glyphicon glyphicon-home">
    </i><span>Inicial</span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria.

Comment: Cara tudo bem, nada contra mas, a sua resposta não funciona dá uma olhada!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic fiz uma edição com algumas melhores práticas, mas vou fazer um teste também!!

Comment: Legal ... agora vai funciona, mudou o aspecto do que ele tinha, mas, vai funciona vlw

Comment: Testado aqui e passou, obrigado por pontuar!!

Answer (score 0):

*Eu achei estranho você colocar na `#nav` do `html`, não seria somente `id="nav"`?*

*Também foi relatado que não é uma boa prática id com mesmo nome, então verifique esse html porque realmente tem imperfeições.!*

Mas existe uma forma que pode funcionar para o seu caso em especifico, exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li a").click(function() {
      var value = $(this)
        .find('i')
        .attr('class')
        .charAt(0);
      console.log(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="a glyphicon glyphicon-home">
    </i><span>Inicial</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="b glyphicon glyphicon-user">
</i>
    <span>Perfil</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="c glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
</i>
    <span>Calendário</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="d glyphicon glyphicon-file">
</i>
    <span>Material Didático</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="e glyphicon glyphicon-stats">
</i>
    <span>Frequencias</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="f glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt">
</i>
    <span>Notas</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="g glyphicon glyphicon-usd">
</i>
    <span>Financeiro</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="h glyphicon glyphicon-book">
    </i><span>Biblioteca</span></a>
</li>
<li><a id="#nav" href="#"><i class="j glyphicon glyphicon-cog">
</i>
    <span>Configurações</span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Tem toda razão! Ao definir o atributo `id` em um elemento não deve ter `#`

Comment: Pois é @SamuelFontebasso estranho essa definição, mas, fica a dica para todos isso não é normal e não funciona inclusive se tiver. Pelo menos comigo não funcionou.

Comment: Sim, inclusive não devemos duplicar um `id` nesse caso o elemento `a` tem que utilizar uma classe como @DavidAlves comentou na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um atributo nas tag de link `<a data-link="valor_atributo" href>` e recuperar este dado no jquery.

o código abaixo está bem simples mas fornece a resposta para a solução.

```js
$("li a").click(function(){
      var variavel = $(this).attr('data-link');
      console.log('o link selecionado foi '+variavel);
     });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li><a data-link="a" href="#"><i class="a glyphicon glyphicon-home">
    </i><span>Inicial</span></a>
</li>
<li><a data-link="b" href="#"><i class="b glyphicon glyphicon-user">
</i>
    <span>Perfil</span></a>
</li>
<li><a data-link="c" href="#"><i class="c glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
</i>
    <span>Calendário</span></a>
</li>
<li><a data-link="d" href="#"><i class="d glyphicon glyphicon-file">
</i>
    <span>Material Didático</span></a>
</li>
<li><a data-link="e" href="#"><i class="e glyphicon glyphicon-stats">
</i>
    <span>Frequencias</span></a>
</li>
<li><a data-link="f" href="#"><i class="f glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt">
</i>
    <span>Notas</span></a>
</li>
<li><a data-link="g" href="#"><i class="g glyphicon glyphicon-usd">
</i>
    <span>Financeiro</span></a>
</li>
<li><a data-link="h" href="#"><i class="h glyphicon glyphicon-book">
    </i><span>Biblioteca</span></a>
</li>
<li><a data-link="j" href="#"><i class="j glyphicon glyphicon-cog">
</i>
    <span>Configurações</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Eu sempre gostei de trabalhar com atributos `data`, é uma abordagem melhor!